# Windows - borders around clicked things

Tags: windows, windows-vista, selection

You know how sometimes where you've clicked there's a dotted border? How do you turn that off? It does it in browsers and some desktop applications (like explorer)

Comment: Depending on the context, that border can be useful, in that it tells you which control currently has the focus.  Can you provide one or two specific examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots show which control is currently focused.
This is very useful if you navigate the GUI with your Keyboard.
You can change the focus with TAB.

I don't think you can turn this off in Windows.

Comment: I understand that it has a purpose. But I'm a little bit OCD, so I'm just wondering how to disable this "feature".

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can remove it by installing the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) extension and then creating a new stylesheet and plugging this in:

```
a:active { outline: none; }
a:focus { -moz-outline-style: none; }
```

I don't think you can remove it in anything outside of browsers though because anything else isn't nearly as configurable.